# Why does my localhost image url change

Tags: asp.net

I have a bunch of images in my localhost folder (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Images) which I am trying to access within my ASP.net application. The image src generated in my markup is:

```
<img id="MainContent_MainImage" src="localhost/Images/FGOStuart_7166.jpg" />`
```

This fails to load the image and if I look at the source for the page it actually directs to

`http://localhost:64395/Pages/localhost/Images/FGOStuart_7166.jpg`

so it looks like it is trying to access a path relative to the page (on the Pages folder). The src works if I type it into the browser manually and the image is displayed.

Can anyone explain what's going on here and how to fix it? I'm attempting to move the images out of the database and onto the file system but without much luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you **really** want to be doing is using the magic tilde:

```
<img id="MainContent_MainImage" runat="server" src="~/Images/FGOStuart_7166.jpg" />
```

`~` signifies the root of the application. Notice I added `runat="server"`, too.

Comment: Thanks, that comes out as http://localhost:64395/Images/FGOStuart_7166.jpg which looks correct but doesn't work unless I remove the :64395 part.

Comment: Huh? The `~` will be replaced with the root URL of your application so the URL you're showing me here is correct. Unless you've got some other weirdness going on? (How is the URL you've pasted not correct?)

Comment: It gives me a 'resource cannot be found' error. If I remove the port number it works. I'm running this directly from VS. I haven't published.

Comment: Looks like there is a separate issue now that the URL is correctly resolved so I'll accept this answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the browser assumes "localhost" is a folder and adds it to the current relative path.  Add http to it and it should work fine, or remove localhost altogether and just leave the /Images... part.

Comment: Adding http seems to make no difference. The resulting URL is the same.

Comment: since you appear to be running on a development web server (from Visual Studio) you would need to add `http://localhost:port_number`, but obviously the answers that have you use ~ are much better in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
<img id="MainContent_MainImage" src="~/Images/FGOStuart_7166.jpg" 
    alt="An Image" runat="server" />
```

This resolves it server-side from the root down. And always use an alt :)